# Is there an increment operator without assignment?

Tags: c++, increment, decrement

This is really a c++ language question more than anything else. I'm curious to know if any such operator exists, or is being developed, or has deprecated.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the increment operator *without changing its value*.

I know that `++var` is equivalent to `var += 1` as far as assignment and that the expression will evaluate to `var + 1` (if it is prefix).

This may be frivolous, but when I have a conditional like

```
if (var + 1 == SOME_CONST) {}
```

I would like to write it more like

```
if (++var == SOME_CONST) {} //not what I want
```

but without changing the value of var:

```
int varDummy = var;
if (++varDummy == SOME_CONST) {}

// Now I want (varDummy == var) to evaluate true, so I wouldn't need varDummy
```

Is this kind of behavior possible? Of course it is nonessential, but I just cringe when I have to use numeric literals. And I don't want operator overloading, because in other contexts I want the increment/decrement operators to behave normally...

Comment: Why do you want to change this? Why is `var + 1` not sufficiënt?

Comment: @Tim It is completely sufficient. I am just used to  using increment operators with local variables when the assignment doesn't matter. All I was trying to find out was if such behavior exists in c++.

Comment: I wonder, why instead of `if (++var == SOME_CONST)` you dont just use `if (var == SOME_OTHER_CONST)` where `SOME_OTHER_CONST=SOME_CONST+1`

Comment: tadpole operator: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150525-00/?p=45044

Comment: @Aposhian So basically, if I understand you correctly, you prefer `++` and `--` over `+=1` and `-=1`  because of the constants?

Comment: @Tim I guess so, but I probably should loosen my preferences. :) But that comes from learning to avoid ambiguous and inflexible code like `index + 7`. But I suppose `+1` is pretty clear.

Comment: @Aposhian Well, I like avoiding constants too. But it really depends on the context. `1` is often the representation of a `whole` or `100%`, which is, by my opinion, appropriate to use. If you could clarify the context, maybe we can help to think of an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this does not exist in the language. It is idiomatic to use `+ 1` for this. Sometimes, numeric literals are appropriate :)

Comment: The language allows to overload operators, and one can certainly overload an increment operator such that it doesn't modify the operand.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly build it using operator overloading, violating the OPs requirements. But it is still not idiomatic, and it still does not exist as such in the language spec :)

Answer (score 2):

you can make it so, if you wish.  e.g.

```
inline int inc(int i) { return i+1; }
```

use a terse function name like inc if you value brevity, or something like one_more_than if you value clarity.

Comment: Although I would expect that to increment the input value - it is what it does in assembler and some flavours of Pascal, amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use numeric literals, you can have the "1" defined just like `SOME_CONST` is defined:

```
#define ADDITIONAL 1

// somewhere else...
if (var + ADDITIONAL == SOME_CONST) {}
```

Or, even better:

```
#define THE_REAL_CONST_YOU_NEED (SOME_CONST - 1)
```

Comment: This might be opinionated, but I absolutely hate this obfuscating style of code, well, probably your answer should not be taken too seriously :)

Comment: @FrankPuffer - If anything the original requirement in the question deserves hatred. Using an explicitly defined operator against its definition is awful, and not doing something obvious and ubiquitous (just `+1`) is not much better - but if the OP has some reasonable excuse (that wasn't shared with us) to want that, using macros is one way to do it. The specific approach is less important, one can even do a macro function that adds 1 (similar to your answer, just as a macro...).

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely do not like the `+1`, you could define an increment function:

```
T inc(T var) {
    return var++;
}
```

(I am using T as a placeholder for a type with increment operator defined. I assume that your `var` is not neccessarily an `int`.)

and then:

```
if (inc(var) == SOME_CONST) {}
```

Comment: might as well go the whole way and make it a template by slipping in `template<typename T>` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

**Looks Nice:**

**`if ( (++var)-- == SOME_CONST) {}`**

Comment: Sure looks nice, but he was looking for an operator *without* assignment and you are recommending one with *two* of them :)

Comment: Obviously all what he was asking for is the look. not a really logical question and he mentioned that. he just doesn't like + 1